# How to give actionbar menu a light background

Tags: android

I want a red toolbar (white icons and white text) but with a popup that has a light background. I cant get the popup background to change to light unless i use a .Light actionbar, which is a problem because it gives me black actionbar text and icons which I don't want

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

I tried changing `android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"` to `android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"` but it makes no difference

Here is my theme

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <!-- <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> -->
</style>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to get it to change

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>



<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there is any way to do this using theme. 
You need to do this using [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)